# How to implement Transfer-Learning with own model

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

I'm trying to save a CNN model I implemented, and use it to perform transfer learning(TL) .
I would like to clarify the following four points. 
1.(CNN code) Whether the model saving method is correct or not. 
2.(TL code) Whether the model loading method is correct or not. 
3.(TL code) How is the "trainable" property of the loaded model usually set? 
4.(TL code) Whether the pre-training model and the subsequent layers are correctly combined (size, etc.)

The following are the model part of the CNN and the transfer learning code. 
Both are regression models that predict two numbers. The input is images (+ supervised data).

```py
#CNN

input = Input(shape=(100,100,3))
conv_0 = Conv2D(32,kernel_size=3,activation='relu')(input)
pool_0 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(conv_0)
pool_0 = Dropout(0.25)(pool_0)
conv_1 = Conv2D(64,kernel_size=3,activation='relu')(pool_0)
pool_1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(conv_1)
pool_1 = Dropout(0.25)(pool_1)
conv_2 = Conv2D(32,kernel_size=3,activation='relu')(pool_1)
pool_2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(conv_2)
pool_2 = Dropout(0.25)(pool_2)
conv_3 = Conv2D(16,kernel_size=3,activation='relu')(pool_2)
pool_3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(conv_3)
conv_4 = Conv2D(8,kernel_size=3,activation='relu')(pool_3)
pool_4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(conv_4)
flat = Flatten()(pool_4)
denseL = Dense(64,activation='relu')(flat)
denseL = Dropout(0.25)(denseL)
A_output = Dense(1,name="a")(denseL)
B_output = Dense(1,name="b")(denseL)

model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=[A_output,B_output])
model.compile(Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
              loss = {'a':'mae','b':'mae'} ,
              metrics =  {'a':'mae','b':'mae'})

history = model.fit([np.array(Img_train)],[np.array(LabelA_train),np.array(LabelB_train)],
                    epochs=100, batch_size=16,
                    validation_data=([np.array(Img_test)],[np.array(LabelA_test),np.array(LabelB_test)]))

model.save('forTransferL.h5')

"""
Outputs for sumally()
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 100, 100, 3) 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)                 (None, 98, 98, 32)   896         input_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 49, 49, 32)   0           conv2d[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)               (None, 49, 49, 32)   0           max_pooling2d[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 47, 47, 64)   18496       dropout[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 23, 23, 64)   0           conv2d_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)             (None, 23, 23, 64)   0           max_pooling2d_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)               (None, 21, 21, 32)   18464       dropout_1[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 10, 10, 32)   0           conv2d_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)             (None, 10, 10, 32)   0           max_pooling2d_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)               (None, 8, 8, 16)     4624        dropout_2[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 4, 4, 16)     0           conv2d_3[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)               (None, 2, 2, 8)      1160        max_pooling2d_3[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 1, 1, 8)      0           conv2d_4[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)               (None, 8)            0           max_pooling2d_4[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                   (None, 64)           576         flatten[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)             (None, 64)           0           dense[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
a (Dense)                       (None, 1)            65          dropout_3[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
b (Dense)                       (None, 1)            65          dropout_3[0][0]
=========================================================================================
"""
```

```py
#TL

model = load_model('forTransferL.h5')
model.layers[0].trainable = False
x = model.layers[10].output

# The following is the same as part of CNN model.
conv_3 = Conv2D(16,kernel_size=3,activation='relu')(x)
pool_3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(conv_3)
conv_4 = Conv2D(8,kernel_size=3,activation='relu')(pool_3)
pool_4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(conv_4)
flat = Flatten()(pool_4)
denseL = Dense(64,activation='relu')(flat)
denseL = Dropout(0.25)(denseL)
A_output = Dense(1,name="a")(denseL)
B_output = Dense(1,name="b")(denseL)

model=Model(inputs=model.input,outputs=[A_output,B_output])
```

Just in case, I also include the error text that is currently appearing below, 
but I think understanding the basic implementation part is a higher priority than fixing the error.

Thank you for your cooperation.

```
#error message

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/userABC/OneDrive/Document/StudyAI/transferMymodel.py", line 158, in <module>
    pool_m4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(conv_m4)
  File "C:\Users\userABC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1006, in __call__
    outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  〜Omitted due to the limited number of characters.

ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for '{{node tf.compat.v1.nn.max_pool_1/MaxPool}} = MaxPool[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", explicit_paddings=[], ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1]](Placeholder)' with input shapes: [?,1,1,8].
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For points 1 and 2, your code seems correct enough, although I personally prefer loading model weights instead of the model itself when it comes to models with custom layers. It doesn't really matter for your situation though.

For points 3, refer to https://keras.io/guides/transfer_learning/:

> If you set trainable = False on a model or on any layer that has sublayers, all children layers become non-trainable as well.

This means that for your situation, setting "model.trainable = False" would freeze all of the weights from the loaded part of the model (prevent it from being changed).

For point 4, the pre-trained model and the later layers looks combined correctly, but the error is caused because you didn't set *padding='same'* inside your Conv2D layers (example:

```
conv_3 = Conv2D(16,kernel_size=3,activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
```

This matters because not indicating same padding means that each Conv2D layer shrinks the image height and width by 2, and given that the output shape from your pretrained model is (8, 8, 16), the first convolution would yield an output shape of (6, 6, 16), the first maxpool would yield (3, 3, 16), the second convolution would yield (1, 1, 8), and at this point, the second max pool can't pool the features anymore since the height and width is smaller than (2, 2).